# Hardware question re Hauppauge WinTV-HVR 900 HD video/tv capture unit used with laptop with HDMI output laptop HDMI connection

Tags: capture

I've ordered a Hauppauge WinTV-HVR 900 HD video/tv capture unit. It is mainly for use with my HP desktop running Windows 7 Professional, but I will want to use it occasionally with my partner's HP laptop running Vista Home Premium. The latter has an HDMI output which works perfectly with my LG 42" LCD TV, enabling display of BBC iPlayer and other catchup services.

Will the live or recorded HD signal from the WinTV-HVR 900 HD connected to the laptop's USB input be output on the laptop's HDMI socket as HD?

Come to that, will SD content be output?

The reason I ask is that I had a problem with a Pinnacle unit which displayed OK on the laptop's screen but not on the TV screen (which did display all the normal Windows material).

I've tried the Hauppage website, but it doesn't even acknowledge the existence of the WinTV-HVR 900 HD!

Comment: [Doesn't acknowledge the existence? Have you tried a Google search for the product name?](http://www.hauppauge.co.uk/site/products/data_hvr900hd.html)

Comment: http://www.hauppauge.co.uk/site/products/data_hvr900hd.html